# Add a list to a list of lists

Tags: ocaml

I've been trying to add a list to a list of lists.

What I want :

```
l1 : [[]] / [] / Empty list
l2 : [1;2]

result : [[1;2]]

add [1;3] to result : 

result : [[1; 2]; [1; 3]]
```

I've tried to play with the @ and the :: operator for quite a while now, still no results.

Here's my problem :

```
type sign = Neg | Zero | Pos | Error

let all_pairs (l1: sign list) (l2 : sign list) : sign list list = 
  let rec aux acc list = 
    match list with 
    | [] -> acc
    | hd :: tl -> 
        let rec m_aux m_acc m_list = 
          match m_list with 
          | [] -> aux (m_acc :: acc) tl
          | m_hd :: m_tl -> m_aux (m_hd :: m_acc) m_tl
        in m_aux [hd] l2

  in aux [] l1
```

With a given L1, L2 which are sign list, return a sign list list with every combination of two signs x and y, x is in L1 and y is in L2

Example :

> L1 : [Pos; Error]
>
> L2 : [Neg; Zero]

all_pairs L1 L2 should return

> [ [Pos; Neg]; [Pos; Zero]; [Error; Neg]; [Error; Zero] ]

In this exact order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand your first line. But here's a session showing how to build up the results you seem to be asking for:

```
# let l1 = [];;
val l1 : 'a list = []
# let l2 = [1;2];;
val l2 : int list = [1; 2]
# let result1 = l1 @ [l2];;
val result1 : int list list = [[1; 2]]
# let l3 = [1;3];;
val l3 : int list = [1; 3]
# let result2 = result1 @ [l3];;
val result2 : int list list = [[1; 2]; [1; 3]]
```

A problem is that you're trying to extend your lists at the end. This isn't natural (or efficient) in OCaml. If you think about a adding new value to the beginning of a list things are simpler.

```
# let result3 = l3 :: l1;;
val result3 : int list list = [[1; 3]]
# let result4 = l2 :: result3;;
val result4 : int list list = [[1; 2]; [1; 3]]
```

The `::` operator adds a new value to the beginning of a list. There's no single operator for adding to the end of a list (because it's not natural or efficient).

**Update**

You can code your function like this:

```
let all_pairs l1 l2 =
    List.concat
        (List.map 
            (fun a -> List.map (fun b -> [a;b]) l2)
             l1)
```

It works for me.

Comment: Thanks ! I was trying "[] @ [1; 2]". In my case, order matters a lot so i'm forced to use the append (@) instead of :: . Maybe it's possible? I'll edit my post with the exact problem I'm trying to solve, please tell me if it's possible if you have the time :)

Comment: It's pretty common to build up a list backward then reverse it at the end. This is much more efficient (for long lists especially) than adding elements one at a time to the end of a list.